# Add a Device Wizard Hangs While Searching For Devices

Tags: windows-7

Steps to reproduce Problem (with a system that is not working correctly):

1. Click on "Devices and Printers"
2. Click "Add a Device"
3. The screen with "Select a Device to Add to this Computer" hangs with the
   message "Searching for devices... Make sure your device is discoverable."

Result: The last screen hangs forever and never lists ANY devices.

[**source**](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprohardware/thread/93fc3a3e-9b94-44ec-a792-c0329fbe7a3e/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, the Add Hardware Wizard can be accessed directly using
`hdwwiz.exe`

Comment: Running hdwwiz.exe isn't always available as a workaround. It needs admin access, whereas my corporate computer is set up without admin access but with rights to add devices.